# "Number of X" or "X" in table headings?

Tags: heading

Would you feel that it is acceptable (in academic writing) to use "Files" and "Lines" instead of "Number of files" and "Number of lines" in table headings when horizontal space is scarce?
Or would you use an abbreviation for "Number of"? If so, which abbreviation is preferable?

**Edit:**
This question is about cardinal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be seen by some as a matter of editorial taste but there is also a logical linguistic aspect to it, to do with redundancy.

I assume that the table is populated with numbers representing the counts or numerical indices of lines and files. If so, it seems redundant to head the columns with “Number of ...” or “No. of ...”. It is sufficient to use “Files” and “Lines”.

Comment: I would use a variant of the numero sign (Nº) for ordinal numbers, but would not feel comfortable doing so for cardinal numbers. "Files" and "Lines" also have an ordinal feel to me.

Comment: A reasonable suggestion, but for the ordinal case (when listing the indices) I would expect “Line Nº” rather than the plural form given on the question. Similarly for file.